# How do you convert this json programming to an xml to submit via vba

Tags: json, xml, vba, gateway

i have this code from a shipping website.  I can submit to the gateway like any other carrier however they don't have a formatted xml example.  They gave this example I wanted to know how to convert it to a properly formatted xml.

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.rocketship.it/v1 \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'x-api-key: YOUR_RS_API_KEY' \
-d '{
"carrier": "UPS",
"action": "track",
"params": {
    "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "tracking_number": "1Z12345E0205271688"
}
}'
```

I just need the tags like submitting to fedex or ups.  This is what i submit to transpak.  It has the xml and xmlhttp code to submit it.

```
XMLRequest1 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" & Chr(34) & " xmlns:xsd=" & Chr(34) & 
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & Chr(34) & " xmlns:soap=" & Chr(34) & 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & Chr(34) & ">" & _
"<soap:Body>" & "<ShipmentInquiry xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://tempuri.org/" 
& Chr(34) & ">" & "<Housebill>" & trackingNumber & "</Housebill>" & _
"</ShipmentInquiry>" & "</soap:Body>" & "</soap:Envelope>"
```

That is teh xml that I need to submit to the example I gave above.  I need it formatted similarly.

```
XML_Method = "POST"

XML_Track_URL = "http://freight.transpak.com/WTKServices/Shipments.asmx"

On Error GoTo 0
TrackTRANSPACK = "Test" ' default if not supported or not tracked by request
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp")
XMLHTTP.Open XML_Method, XML_Track_URL, False
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
XMLHTTP.send XML_Request1 ' okay to send blank string, if not needed (non-UPS tracking)
TrackTRANSPACK = CStr(XMLHTTP.responseText)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: json programming?

Comment: @KolobCanyon yes it looks like it is json programming.  I need the json converted to xml.  I converted it with a converter but I don't think it is right.  I need that code converted to vba.

Comment: Are you sure they even support XML ?

Comment: @TimWilliams ok i just found out that they don't support xml.  I have to submit a json string in vba.  I tried piecing a json string together but it isn't working. It says that -H isn't a litteral.  It iwll work if I submit the proper json string to the gateway.  Any ideas on what that would look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+post+json   You're confusing the curl tool arguments with the json payload.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to submit a json string to get a json response.

```
XML_Request1 = "{" & Chr(34) & "carrier" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & 
"fedex" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "type" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & 
"TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG" & Chr(34) & "," & _
Chr(34) & "action" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "track" & Chr(34) & "," & 
Chr(34) & "parameters" & Chr(34) & ": {" & Chr(34) & "key" & Chr(34) & ": " 
& Chr(34) & "key" & Chr(34) & "," & _
Chr(34) & "password" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "password" & Chr(34) & "," 
& Chr(34) & "meterNumber" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "meter number" & 
Chr(34) & "," & _
Chr(34) & "accountNumber" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "account" & Chr(34) & 
"," & Chr(34) & "service" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & 
"GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY" & Chr(34) & "," & _
Chr(34) & "tracking_number" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & trackingNumber & 
Chr(34) & "}}"
```

I went to a json online formatter to put together the proper string:

```
{
"carrier": "fedex",
"type": "TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG",
"action": "track",
"parameters": {
  "key": "YOURKEY",
  "password": "YOURPASS",
  "meterNumber": "YOURMETER",
  "accountNumber": "510087348",
  "service": "GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY",
  "tracking_number": "."
 }
}
```

I submitted the payload and got a valid response.